# unity 2d invisible sprites

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, invisible

Im about to make something game like. A character walking and jumping in unity.

Have in mind that im total beginner in unity.

But what's my problem, is that sprites creating my character suddenly dissapeared. Only 1 Arm and glow stayed visible. Sprites are existing and they're not hidden behind other layers . They're just invisible. What's the difference between arm and the rest of sprites i noticed is that in inspector of arm i see mesh renderer and in the other ones skinned mesh renderer. I suppose skinned mesh means that sprites can be animated, but i don't understand why it creates such problem. Also, as you can see sprites are bounded to bones. I noticed some error, do you know what does it mean?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz9bm.jpg)

Thank you in advance

/edit

[when i click error, unity shows me this, 577](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzRjA.png)

The override geometry error and unity message:

> Not allowed to override geometry on sprite 'back'
>   UnityEngine.Sprite:OverrideGeometry(Vector2[], UInt16[])
>   Anima2D.SpriteMeshPostprocessor:DoSpriteOverride(SpriteMesh, Sprite)
>   (at Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/SpriteMeshPostprocessor.cs:577)
>   Anima2D.SpriteMeshPostprocessor:OnPostprocessSprites(Texture2D,
>   Sprite[]) (at
>   Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/SpriteMeshPostprocessor.cs:532)
>   UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:StopAssetEditing()
>   Anima2D.SpriteMeshPostprocessor:Initialize() (at
>   Assets/Anima2D/Scripts/Editor/SpriteMeshPostprocessor.cs:86)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallDelayFunctions()

Comment: You have an error in your console. Its probably important. What is it?

Comment: Yes, as is sad, i don't know how to fix it, also i didn't coded anything yet

Comment: I think This is related to Sorting Layers. add separate layers for the body parts and add them to sorting layer in the sprites inspector.

Comment: No, show me the error. What is that error?

Comment: Well, i added 1 more picture and unity message in edit :) Let me know if it's not really what you wanted to know. thank you in advance